# How do I cook frozen Goya Empanadas in the microwave?

Tags: microwave

How do I cook frozen Goya Pizza Empanadas in the microwave?

Comment: Does the package have instructions?

Answer (score 1):

This from [their website](http://www.wegmans.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?productId=348506&storeId=10052&langId=-1):

> Directions
>
> Keep frozen. Cooking: In a skillet or deep fryer at 325 degrees F,
>   preheat enough oil to cover the empanadas. Fry for four minutes or
>   until golden, turning occasionally. Drain on paper towel. For Best
>   Results: Fry from frozen state. ***We do not recommend cooking product in
>   microwave oven.***

This suggests to me that there is no good way to cook these in the microwave.

Having said that, there is probably nothing dangerous about cooking them in the microwave, although I generally keep a close eye on anything I've never microwaved before just in case. You may need to experiment cooking from frozen vs. cooking from thawed but there are four of them in a box so knock yourself out.

If getting the surface to brown is a problem you could try using a microwave crisper. Microwave crispers come in a couple of forms: a reusable bag (a bit like a popcorn bag) marketed under the name "Brown and Crisp" and what looks like a non-stick steel pan. If these aren't readily available I don't imagine they will make such a difference to your end result that it will be worth ordering them specially.